# Doctrine 2 multi-level OneToOne Cascade

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, mapping, doctrine-orm

I have three Doctrine entities: Device, which has a OneToOne relationship with Device\Status, which in turn has a OneToOne relationship with Device\Status\Battery.

I have {cascade="persist"} set between the related entities, and from what I've read, that should be all that is required for Doctrine to automatically persist each of the entities without having to do anything myself in the code.

Here's what I'm having problems with:

```
$device = new \Entities\Device();
$device->setId(100);

$status = $device->getStatus();
$status->setIpAddress('192.168.0.1');

$battery = $status->getBattery();
$battery->setInternalLevel(60);

$em->persist($device);
$em->flush();
```

After executing this code, I get the following error:

```
Entity of type Device\Status\Battery has identity through a foreign entity 
Device\Status, however this entity has no identity itself. You have to call 
EntityManager#persist() on the related entity and make sure that an identifier 
was generated before trying to persist 'Device\Status\Battery'. In case of 
Post Insert ID Generation (such as MySQL Auto-Increment or PostgreSQL SERIAL) 
this means you have to call EntityManager#flush() between both persist 
operations.
```

My question is: what is the correct way to setup my entities to ensure that they're persisted in the correct order?

The code for the entities can be found here: https://gist.github.com/1753524

All tests have been performed using the Doctrine 2.2 sandbox.

Comment: I had almost same problem. U have to call flush between each persist.

Comment: @CappY According to the Doctrine docs, since I have {cascade="persist"} set for each entity, I don't need to manually persist each entities. This code *should* work as is. http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations

Comment: Please provide a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/). Your code triggers an access violation when attempting to assign values directly to `protected` properties, ie `$device->id = 100`

Comment: what if after setting each attribute you set the inverse side too? something like this: after `$status->device = $device;` you do `$device->status = $status;`, and then after `$battery->status = $status;` you do `$status->battery = $battery;`

Comment: @jere I'm actually already doing that, but had neglected to reflect it in my example code. Updated example code now includes the inverse assignments.

Comment: i think @CappY is right. the problem is in the Status entity. when you do `getBattery()` and create a new Battery instance, it's related to the Status instance on which you called `getBattery()`. since that instance hasn't been stored in the database yet, it's id hasn't been generated (because it's annotated as GeneratedValue). you're almost right about cascade persist. except for that it's performed *in memory*

Comment: @jere Nertz, I was afraid of that. I was hoping to not have to manually persist the Status. If you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think @CappY is right.

The problem is in the Status entity. when you do `getBattery()` and create a new Battery instance, it's related to the Status instance on which you called `getBattery()`.

Since that instance hasn't been stored in the database yet, it's id hasn't been generated (because it's annotated as `@GeneratedValue`). you're almost right about cascade persist. except for that it's performed *in memory*.

So you **need** to persist and flush Status entity before doing `getBattery()` if you want to use that entity as id in Battery. Or else you could simple add an id field for Battery :)

Comment: I just realized I actually had to press the "+50" button to award the bounty, and not just accept your answer. So there you go :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add cascade={"persist"} to your relation mapping. The answer you selected as correct is also correct but with that solution, if anything goes wrong after the parent data is inserted, there will be no transaction rollback. You have to set autocommit=false and perform commit transaction manually. With cascade={"persist"} you dont have to. Anything goes wrong during database action, everything will be rollbacked.

Comment: That's what he was doing and it didn't work. Can you provide a full example working?